# Unity Object bounces even before colliding with a boundary collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

Im making a carrom kind of game where Im using physics for striker movement, the problem is my striker object bounces from the edge of the board even before there was a real collision between my striker object collider and the board edge colliders.
Please check this video where I have highlighted my project setup, is I'm doing anything wrong here?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xifD--sXHvQWjLbud-Lpt-qG3GAXu-hS/view?usp=sharing

I tried to fix it in many ways but wasn't able to reduce this offset and without resolving this issue I wasn't able to proceed further, because if there are 2 objects very near to each other and if the striker hits only one of those objects accurately still the nearest another object is also considering it as a collision even though there wasn't a real collision!

Is this a known bug? if not how can I remove this offset and can have accurate collisions that are required for carrom kind of games (where multiple objects are near to other)?

Comment: That looks strange. Have you tried messing around with the physics settings, such as the Default Contact Offset? Or tried using Continous collision detection instead? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ContinuousCollisionDetection.html

Comment: As @eligolf said try playing with collision detection settings and rigidbody interpolations,  or you could just manually move your edge collider a little back.

Comment: What else is attached to the red thing that stops short? A rigidbody uses all the colliders in all child game objects, not just the collider where the rigidbody is located.

Comment: @eligolf Yeah, I tried to play with those but none of them made any difference!

Comment: @Rajas Yup, but I don't want to use rigid body interpolation basically, so for now I have kept it as none, if I choose extrapolation then the striker object sometimes intersects with the edge colliders and if I select interpolate the same issue persists, Im making a carrom kind of game where I need bit more accurate physics simulation.

Comment: @Chuck In the above video I have enabled physics debug view, the red object is my striker and it doesn't have any big child hierarchy, only 4 objects are under it. but still, I have tried deleting that as well but didn't make any difference, also Im not using multiple colliders only one mesh collider is added to my striker object and the remaining green area is the board edge colliders.

Comment: This question isn't about [tag:unityscript], it is about [tag:c#]

Answer (score 0):

I got the mistake that I have done!
In the editor, every time while going to play mode striker object collision detection mode was set to "Continuous Speculative" and at run time I used to change it to "Discrete" or "Continuous" or "Continuous Dynamic" assuming I will be able to change it at run time but that's not the case, even though editor allows us to change collision detection mode at run time, technically it will only consider the mode which was set initially(i.e while starting the play mode), so If I have to see the behavior of "Continuous Dynamic" then I have to stop the play mode and set collision detection mode to "Continuous Dynamic" and run it again!